# Reversing share library written in C to extract port number with GDB

Tags: c, linux, gdb, reverse-engineering

I am looking for help with GDB to reverse engineer shared library written in C that is preloaded in /etc/ld.so.preload.

Current library hooks accept() call if source port is correct it returns reverse shell back to user.

Strings command doesn't give out source port, so my target is to try to find it within GDB.

Program consist of two files headers.h where I have my definitions and variable `#define SECRET_PORT 11111`
source.c contains accept hook with reverse shell.

My problem is I cannot figure out a way how to retrieve PORT within GDB - I can load mylib.so within gdb and run: `info functions` to see whats inside - I can see accept function but when I try to `disass accept` I only get instructions that I barely can understand.

1. Problem when I run mylib it gives out SIGSEGV (maybe thats the reason I cannot see variables) there is no main function where to set break and if I do set it on function accept is still gives SIGSEGV error.
2. I tested with `starti` instead of run then I got `Program stopped 0xSOMEADRESGOESHERE in deregister_tm_clones()` I don't even know if this is correct way to test .so file. maybe there are some oser switches.

Im thinking I need to find a way how to set BP in HTONS() checking function where if statement compares source port and extract values from there but so far no luck.

p.s. when mylib is loaded in gdb there is message No debugging symbols found. So I cannot run like list accept or anything like that to view a source.

Compilation code `gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC mylib.c -o mylib.so -ldl`

Comment: > I only get instructions that I barely can understand

Understanding instructions is a must for reverse engineering. You could find the instruction that checks the supplied port value, comparing it with `SECRET_PORT`. You won’t find the constant itself anywhere else, not to mention its name which disappeared during preprocessing (even before actual compilation).

Comment: Run `strace` on the application.

Comment: @numzero Yes I understand that. Not so much experience but I can see in disass accept  instruction list there are two things after htons@plt there is "cmp %ax,%bx" after that there is jne 0x1345 <accept+222> and test $eax,$eax  - I already tried to run mylib then "info registers $eax" that gave me 0xf7ffe0a8 -134225752   (I can't undestand if im getting instannt SIGSEGV fault with 0x000....01 is correct behavior or not) maybe those cmp/test checks are not populated with anything

Comment: @kaylum it didn't work with strace but ltrace did the trick I can see that for example running some file that includes mylib I see function call(s) with some addresses

Answer (score 0):

> Im thinking I need to find a way how to set BP in HTONS() checking function where if statement compares source port and extract values from there

You *don't* need to do that -- the instructions will be the *same* whether you run the application, or disassemble the function *without* running.

> Compilation code ...

So you are trying to reverse-engineer the library for which you have a source?
That makes it *very easy* to find the constant you are looking for.

Start by setting the constant to easily recognizable value, e.g. `0x12131415`. Compile the library and disassemble it. Look for your constant.

If you don't see it, save the disassembled output, and rebuild the library with a different value, e.g. `0xA1B1C1D1`. Disassemble it again and compare to previous disassembled output. It should be easy to spot the difference.

P.S. If you *really* want to debug this library with a live process, do this:

```
gdb ./myprog
(gdb) set env LD_PRELOAD /path/to/mylib.so
(gdb) run
```

At this point, you should be able to set breakpoints and observe your library "in action".

Comment: Thank You for input - will try this method and report back how it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed solve this with a help

when running GDB on shared library You will have to check hex value for 11111 and it should be 2B67 so in registers this will become something like 0x2b67 & it will be passed to htons() as check for source port.

So let's assume I didn't have the source code I could still run: `gdb -q *.so`
then: `info functions` and see with `disass functionNameGoesHere` where some accept / htons calls are made. Correct value should be found right above htons line.
Then decoded hex to dec and thats how You can find it.

This took some while to figure out as I coudn't set BP's.

Again thanks for input from community! Cheers